# Is Faker name generation duplication possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faker

Can someone confirm that the Faker [name generation](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/blob/master/lib/faker/default/name.rb) can create duplicate names or parts of names?

If I create two users, is there a possibility that one user would have the same first_name as the last_name of another user? I can see that there are [identical names](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/blob/master/lib/locales/en/name.yml) used for both male first and last names and female first and last names. So, I could have Carter Cole for the first user and Bailey Carter for the second user for example.

If I create two users, is it possible that both users have the same first and last names. Like Daniel Fay and Daniel Fay for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but I guess such situation can happen. However, faker has tool to avoid such situation. Have you read this [paragraph](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker#ensuring-unique-values) ?

Prefix your method call with `unique`. For example:

```
Faker::Name.unique.name # This will return a unique name every time it is called
```

If too many unique values are requested from a generator that has a limited number of potential values, a `Faker::UniqueGenerator::RetryLimitExceeded` exception may be raised. It is possible to clear the record of unique values that have been returned, for example between tests.

`Faker::Name.unique.clear # Clears used values for Faker::Name`
`Faker::UniqueGenerator.clear # Clears used values for all generators`

You also can give some already used values to the unique generator if you have collisions with the generated data (i.e: using FactoryBot with random and manually set values).

Usage:
`Faker::<generator>.unique.exclude(method, arguments, list)`

Add `'azerty'` and `'wxcvbn'` to the string generator with 6 char length
`Faker::Lorem.unique.exclude :string, [6], %w[azerty wxcvbn]`